# custom side nav menu in Durandal changing style on active

Tags: javascript, html, menu, nav, durandal

I have a custom asize nav menu, with a list of MenuItem in a array, I bind this list to a ul with a foreach, and the properties of MenuItem to the li, such as; isActive, Name, Link, Icon.

I then setup the route to the view they are linking to

```
router.mapRoute('games', 'viewmodels/games', 'games');
```

I am now trying to change the menu item css style to an active style when I am on that view, but I am not sure how to get into the scope of that event, or what to register a callback for such an event. Once I am in the event I need to get reference to the menuItem or ko.observable of its isActive, which I am also unsure of how to do.

Any help appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think that if the only thing that you want is to change the css when the view is active and when it is not. You can implement that in a similar way as in the hot towel example done by John Papa.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
        <a class="brand" href="/">
            <span class="title">Hot Towel SPA</span> 
        </a>
        <div class="btn-group" data-bind="foreach: router.visibleRoutes">
            <a data-bind="css: { active: isActive }, attr: { href: hash }, text: name" 
                class="btn btn-info" href="#"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="loader pull-right" data-bind="css: { active: router.isNavigating }">
            <div class="progress progress-striped active page-progress-bar">
                <div class="bar" style="width: 100px;"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

I have got this example from: https://github.com/johnpapa/HotTowel